# How to reset LineGraph and x-axis labels

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have two Line Graphs insert into two buttons which Line Graph A have Index of 4 and Size 4 and Line Graph B have Index of 3 and Size 3 for my x-Axis Values. I'm able to traverse Button **B>A**, But unable to traverse back to Button **A>B** as it will crash. The error prompt was due to my formatting issues which stated `IndexOutOfBounds`.

I have tried `Linechart.clear();` at the start of the button `setOnClickListner`, but it doesn't work.

I'm expecting the result to be, Whenever I click Button A, it will show the values I want and x-axis labels and Whenever I click Button B, it will show the values I want and x-axis labels using the same line graph

Comment: I'm using MPAndroidChart for line-graphs

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your chart view that the dataset is updated for that add following lines:

```
    yourChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    yourChart.invalidate();
```